# Cannot create elasticSearch Domain using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-elasticsearch

I'm trying to create elasticsearch cluster using terraform.

Using terraform 0.11.13

Please can someone point out why I'm not able to create log groups? What is the Resource Access Policy? is it the same as the data "aws_iam_policy_document" I'm creating?

Note: I'm using  elasticsearch_version = "7.9"

code:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "search_test_log_group" {
  name = "/aws/aes/domains/test-es7/index-logs"
}

resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain" "amp_search_test_es7" {
  domain_name           = "es7"
  elasticsearch_version = "7.9"

  .....
  log_publishing_options {
    cloudwatch_log_group_arn = "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.search_test_log_group.arn}"
    log_type                 = "INDEX_SLOW_LOGS"
    enabled                  = true
  }


  access_policies = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.elasticsearch_policy.json}"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "elasticsearch_policy" {
  version = "2012-10-17"

  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      identifiers = ["*"]
      type        = "AWS"
    }

    actions   = ["es:*"]
    resources = ["arn:aws:es:us-east-1:xxx:domain/test_es7/*"]
  }

  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      identifiers = ["es.amazonaws.com"]
      type        = "Service"
    }

    actions = [
      "logs:PutLogEvents",
      "logs:PutLogEventsBatch",
      "logs:CreateLogStream",
    ]

    resources = ["arn:aws:logs:*"]
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error

```
aws_elasticsearch_domain.test_es7: Error creating ElasticSearch domain: ValidationException: The Resource Access Policy specified for the CloudWatch Logs log group /aws/aes/domains/test-es7/index-logs does not grant sufficient permissions for Amazon Elasticsearch Service to create a log stream. Please check the Resource Access Policy.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ElasticSearch (ES) to be able to write to CloudWatch (CW) Logs, you have to provide a [resource-based](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html) policy on your CW logs.

This is achieved using [aws_cloudwatch_log_resource_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_log_resource_policy) which is missing from your code.

In fact, TF docs have a ready to use example of how to do it for ES, thus you should be able to just copy and paste it.

ES [access policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-ac.html) are different from CW log policies, as they determine who can do what on your ES domain. Thus, you would have to adjust that part of your code to meet your requirements.